# How to automatically stop AlarmManager

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I want to start my code from N o'clock, then run until Y o'clock. I use `AlarmManager` to achieve it as follows:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

Intent intent = new Intent("net.arkellyga.checkservice");
intent.putExtra("text", etmessage.getText().toString());
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

// If service working now.
am.cancel(pendingIntent);
Log.i("AlarmManager", "Start working from " + d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes());

am.set(AlarmManager.RTC, d.getTime(), pendingIntent);
am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, d.getTime(), 60000, pendingIntent);
```

It works perfectly! But how can I stop the service? I need `AlarmManager` to automatically stop at Y o'clock.

With best regards, Arkellyga.

Comment: Can you write another alarm that will run at Y and cancel first alarm?

Comment: Create new intentservice and stop first alarm in service?